# Does cmvision save framennnn.jpg files?

Tags: ros, cmvision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can cmvision somehow save a frame0000.jpg file?  I've run colorgui.launch, blobfinder.launch and cmvision.launch while trying to learn this package, and I found this JPG in my turtlebot directory above my cmvision directory.  Where did it come from?  How can I do it again?  ;>)

Alan  KM6VV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56359/does-cmvision-save-framennnn.jpg-files?/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

image_view saves images in that format when you right click.

(didn't know there were other hams on here - 73 de N1LAZ)

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on 2013-02-27**:
Thanks, now if I can just get image_view working again.  Yes, a few hams here, does ROS run on Ham radios?